# Pivot Query with Double header

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have prepared a pivot query that works from a simple table of

```
Team (NVarchar), ApptOutcome (NVarchar), PatientID (int), 'Under 16' As LeftColumn.
```

Input data..

```
North Team, Attended, 1000
North Team, DNA, 1000
South Team, DNA, 2000
South Team, Cancelled, 3000

etc etc..
```

I want an output that counts the `PatientID` for each Team(only 2), for each Outcome (only 3 outcomes, `Attended`, `DNA`, `Cancelled`) and LeftColumn on the left!

So basically I need a double header using `Team` and `Outcome`. So far I have it working for Team! see code and output below...

```
SELECT 
    Team, [Attended] AS Attended, [DNA] AS DNA, [Cancelled] AS Cancelled
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Team, ApptOutcome, PatientID
     FROM 
         Under16) ps
PIVOT
    (COUNT(PatientID)
         FOR ApptOutcome IN ( [Attended], [DNA], [Cancelled])
    ) AS pvt
```

Current Output:

```
    Team    Attended    DNA Cancelled
  North Team    299     21     22
  South Team    10      5       1
```

Expected Output:

```
                  Attended                  DNA               Cancelled

Left Column    NorthTeam, SouthTeam, NorthTeam, SouthTeam, NorthTeam, SouthTeam

Under 16         100          150     20        21        2         4
```

Comment: please clear your input and output data...

Comment: so your query seems fine to give you this output on this input, what is your concern, if this is giving any error they kindly post that.

Comment: My query works of course, but I need it with 'left column' on the left and Team and ApptOutcome as a double header across the top!

Comment: then post that expected output data.

Comment: This belongs in the presentation layer

Comment: Cant be done in sql ?